# Passing Django form class as function parameter

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to reuse the 'edit' view below by passing a 'ModelForm' class (not an instance) as a parameter. The simplified code is below:

```
def edit(request, id, form_class):

    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=id) 

    if not request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(instance=person)

    else:
        form = form_class(request.POST, instance=person)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(show_person), args=(id,))

    return render_to_response('edit_person.html', {'form' : form, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def edit_person_name(request, id):
    return edit(request, id, PersonForm_NameOnly)

def edit_person_birthday(request, id):
    return edit(request, id, PersonForm_BirthdayOnly)
```

`PersonForm_NameOnly` and 'PersonForm_BirthdayOnly' are form classes which inherit from `ModelForm`.

Unfortunately the above does not validate but gives an an error that some required form fields are missing. However if instead of using the `form_class` variable, I use directly the class name instead (`PersonForm_NameOnly` or `PersonForm_BirthdayOnly`) everything works fine.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Edit:
The error I get is a form validation error:
"This field is required."

This is because I have a field in my 'Person' model which is required and for some reason it is not set when I do:
"form = form_class(request.POST, instance=person)"

This results in form.is_valid() to fail with the above error when I display the form in my template.

Comment: Can you give an example of the errors?

Comment: @ted: It is correct. show_person is a view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: The error I get is a form validation error:  * This field is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in your `edit_person.html` template?  Is the POST target URL hardcoded, and set to the wrong view?

E.g. is your `PersonForm_NameOnly` form being submitted to `edit_person_birthday` by mistake, or is your `PersonForm_BirthdayOnly` form being submitted to `edit_person_name` by mistake?